# variavel global angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A pergunta é simples, antes da função eu declarei `splited` e dentro da função altero `splited` para o valor retornado no `response`, agora, depois da função quando dou `console.log` retorna vazio. Porque?

```
var splited;
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
shows.get($scope.id).then(function(response) {
  // splita url video to get only video id
  var video = response.video_url;
  splited = video.split("=")[1];
});
console.log(splited);
```

Comment: Tenta declarar a variável no `$rootScope`, acho que assim resolve o seu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada no ngResource, um exemplo que fiz no meu service.

```
 var services = angular.module('ProcessoService', ['ngResource']);

    services.factory('ProcessosFactory', function($resource,apiUrl){
      var resource = $resource('http://restTest/retornos');

      var factory = {
          listar: function () {        
              var lista = resource.query({}, function(data){
                 lista = data;
              });
              return lista;
          }


      }


  return factory;
```

no controller só chama:

$scope.lista = ProcessosFactory.listar();

Esse método serve para retornar uma lista ou apenas um objeto.

Answer (score 5):

A função que é passada para o método `then` não é executada de maneira síncrona. Ela só será executada quando o resultado de `shows.get` estiver disponível.

Mas a linha `console.log(splited)` é executada imediatamente após a chamada a `shows.get`. Nesse momento, a função do `then` ainda não foi executada, e o valor da sua variável `splited` está com o seu valor original (`undefined`).

Comment: Complementando, mover o console para dentro do `.then()` irá mostrar o valor correto.

Comment: o problema é que eu preciso pegar o valor do `splited` após chamar a função, é possível rodar a função assycronamente?

Comment: A função está sendo executada assincronamente. Você só pode executar algum código que dependa do valor da variável `splitted` depois que o seu valor for calculado - como sugeriu @CelsomTrindade, coloque essa lógica dentro da função passada pro `then`, e não fora dela.

Comment: com esse retorno do `splited` eu chamo uma função do youtube que carrega um player, mas esse player só aparece depois que dou f5 na página, porque?

Comment: Provavelmente está em algum processo que não dispara o digest. Tente adicionar isso ao final da função: '$scope.$apply()' e veja se resolve